# PHP select images and show the main image if exist

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Currently I'm using 2 statements to select data from my database, but I'm sure it would be possible with only one, I just can't figure out how. I have id, productid, thumbnailimage, is_mainimage in my database.
The 'is_mainimage' cell can be 0 or 1. 1 if it's main image. I'd like to select all the images but only display the main image on the bootstrap cards if there is main image. If there isn't, then show a static image from my folder. And if a user click on the card, it should show a modal with the other images.
This is how it looks like atm:

```
// Thumbnail images
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid=?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $productid);
$productid = $row['id'];
$stmt->execute();
$result2 = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Main image
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid=? AND is_mainimage=?";
$stmt2 = $link->prepare($sql3);
$stmt2->bind_param("ii", $productid, $is_mainimage);
$productid = $row['id'];
$is_mainimage = 1;
$stmt2->execute();
$result3 = $stmt2->get_result();
$data2 = $result3->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

the top of my card where I display the main image or the static 'no-image.png'

```
<?php
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
if ($num_rows == 1) {
    foreach ($data2 as $rec2) {
        $mainimage = $rec2['thumbnailimage'];
    }
} else {
    $mainimage = "images/no-image.png";
}

echo "<img src='" . $mainimage . "' class='card-img-top' alt='Main Image'/>";
```

So my question is, how to do it with only one select to be able to use the remaining images?

Comment: where is `$is_mainimage` defined? Is that prior to the first sql command shown here? If yes then the first command is redundant and also where is `$productid` initially defined and why query the db using that as input only to return exactly that piece of data from the query?

Comment: I gave it a value with ```$is_mainimage = 1``` because I needed those in the main image statement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you. Could you show it on my code what should I change?

Comment: If you changed your query to: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid = ? ORDER BY is_mainimage DESC`, you'll get all images for that product, with the image that has `is_mainimage` set to `1` as the first result.

Comment: And how can I display only the mainimage on the card if I need the rest on the modal? And how to handle if there's no image?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you could do it.  It's just up to you to select the control structure that's easiest for you.  For instance, you might change your query to this:

```
SELECT productid, 
    group_concat(if(is_mainimage, thumbnailimage, null)) as mainImage,
    group_concat(if(is_mainimage, null, thumbnailimage)) as thumbnails
FROM images 
WHERE productid = ?
GROUP BY productid
```

which would give you one row for the productID, with either the file or null for the main image, and the thumbnails concatenated together with a separator (you can specify the separator to use).  In this case, you would check if mainImage was null, and if so then use your default image.  Then for the thumbnails you would explode them on the delimiter, then use that array to fill in your other images.

Or, you could

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE productid = ?
```

and then do something like this with the results:

```
$main = false;
$thumbnails = [];

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $image = $row['thumbnailimage'];
    if($row['is_mainimage']) { $mainimage = $image; }
    else { $thumbnails[] = $image; }
}
```

and you'll end up with $mainimage either being an image or false, and an array of the other images.  Then you can check $mainimage's value and force the default if you need to:

```
if(!$mainimage) { $mainimage = 'images/no-image.png'; }
```

and then use the $thumbnails array to generate the html for your other images.

There are a lot of ways you could set it up.  Just depends on what makes most sense to you.